# Using Powershell script for multiple disks formatting

Tags: azure-powershell

PowerShell script for formatting multiple disks

need Powershell script I'm Serching for this content but did not get any script

Answer (score 0):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to delete the Multiple disks using PowerShell**

As I tried below script to delete the multiple disks.

```
#List all disks 
Get-Disk 
 #List disks that are required to Format   Get-Partition –DiskNumber 2,3
 # Clear the require Drives Clear-Disk -Number 3,2 –RemoveData 
 #Initializes 
 Initialize-Disk -Number 2,3 
 # Set Drive Name to the Drive 
 New-Partition -DiskNumber 2,3 -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel myDrive 
 # Set Drive Letter to the Drive 
 Get-Partition -DiskNumber 3 | Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter S
```

[image: (https://i.imgur.com/6Sq2lwm.png)]

[image]